Tidal bore during hurrican Ian
Hurricane Ian destroyed a railroad bridge several miles upstream of the mouth of the Caloosahatchie river.    The pilings for the bridge were snapped off  which would seem to indicate a massive lateral force striking the bridge. Is there any possibility that a tidal bore was generated by the hurricane.  If so, how can this be verified.

The bridge was destroyed by the storm surge https://www.news-press.com/story/news/local/2022/10/21/seminole-gulf-railway-bridges-hurricane-ian-damage-murder-mystery-dinner-train-fort-myers/10560540002/ but this does not seem like the typical situation for a bore wave. A tidal bore is usually formed when a river opens into a large bay. This is not the case here.

This might be more suited to [earthscience.se]
